# Translate $date into Dutch

Tags: magento-1.9, language, date

I want to translate the displayed date into Dutch.
My current code looks like this:

```
<?php
$post = $this->getPost();
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date');
?>

<span class="date"><?php echo $date->date('d F Y', $post->getCreatedTime()); ?></span>
```

But that does display the date as `07 March 2016`. I want to translate the Month to Dutch, so it will be `7 Maart 2016`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mage_Core_Helper_Data::format()`  it will format the date according to the locale settings.

```
Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($date->date('d F Y', $post->getCreatedTime()), 'medium', false);
```

[reference](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-dates-in-magento/) for understanding the date better

Comment: That's maybe a better/more Magento solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the locale to Dutch:

`setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');`

Comment: More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php